# Dualboot or Virtualbox any performance differences?

Tags: 14.04

Virtualbox mostly uses lot of cpu and memory from my laptop, what if I install ubuntu dual boot instead using virtualbox, is it gona increase ubuntu performance dramatically? Also which one is better for ruby development performance dual boot or virtualbox ?

Comment: unless you really need to have both of the machines/OSs available at a given time, you better use dualboot. The performance difference is huge as Jeremie has pointed, especially due to the Unity desktop. However there is a nice workaround for Unity here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/ubuntu-14-04-classic-gnome-flashback-session .

Comment: @Wolfgang that is not a workaround, it is an alternative. Also, please link to the official page, not an article about it.

Comment: @Tim get some chill man...

Comment: I have plenty of "chill" I assure you, I was just politely explaining what was wrong with the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, running on bare metal will be significantly faster, especially in areas of graphics or CPU/RAM intensive tasks.

Comment: This is especially apparent when running the Unity desktop environment: When booting Ubuntu directly, Unity will be butter-smooth because it can use the built-in graphics card of your computer. When using Ubuntu inside Virtualbox, performance is often very slow and there might be graphics issues, depending on your setup.

Comment: The amount of RAM really matters too. On my home machine (Ubuntu native) with 16G of RAM I can run a VBox of a Windows7 (4G virtual ram) which feels almost native (bar games or 3D apps). Just go to 8G of RAM and it stars to feel sluggy.